# Что означает следующий синтаксис в bash скрипте?

Tags: bash

```
if [ "${2:0:8}" = fix ]
```

А точнее сама запись аргумента сравнения?

```
${2:0:8}
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html взять из переменной первые 8 символов. Довольно бессмысленная запись потому что равенство будет только если переменная равна `fix`, так что можно было просто сравнить `"$2" = fix`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Почему же бессмысленная? `равенство будет только если переменная равна fix, так что можно было просто сравнить "$2" = fix` -  Вы не правы, только когда первые 8 символов будут равны переменной `fix`, Мб выше в программе проверяются первые 7 символов, вы же не знаете задумку автора

Comment: @ВадимАлександру  том-то и дело, что не переменной `fix`, а строке `fix`.

Comment: Простите, я заменил правую часть т.к. думал, что она не играет роли, теперь, когда я понял смысл записи слева, все стало на свои места и замечание вполне уместно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Извлекает подстроку длинной 8 символов из второго аргумента.
Для теста можно создать файл `s.sh`
с содержимым

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "${2:0:8}"
```

запускаем

```
$ ./s.sh first texttexttext
```

И смотрим вывод

```
$ texttext
```

Comment: укажите, что 0 - это позиция, а 8 - это длина. аля `${FOOOOOO:0:3}` извлечение подстроки с нулевой позиции длиной 3